# Placing a Div inside a Div

Tags: css

I have a parent div id=A which has a width of 100%. I want that all the elements of the div A should be placed to the right.

So I added another div id=B inside A and did a text-align=right on the div A. The width of B is 600px.

However the controls appear left aligned in A. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do a `float: right` on the div B

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer

Comment: Additional info: Check out the CSS display attribute. A DIV is, by default, a block element, so will not follow the rules of text-align, only inline elements will follow this.

Comment: If you want "that all the elements of the div A should be placed to the right", take a look at my answer (#A *{float:right})

Answer (score 1):

Just go :

```
#A * {
  text-align: right;
}
```

If you want the actual div to be right align and not just the text, use float:right instead.

```
#A *{
 float:right;
}
```

You might need to specify a width for #B. If you don't want to do that here's a solution:

```
#B{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: The width of B is set (cf; question). And inline-block won't work on IE if it's applied to a div element.

Comment: inline-block is not a real option... besides, div's are already "block" elements. You can specify a width already.

Comment: if you don't want to set the width, inline block is nice. the OP said that he wanted "all the elements" floating right, hence the idea of using inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
 direction:rtl;
}
</style>
<h3>Welcome to the real-time HTML editor!</h3>
<p>Type HTML in the textarea above, and it will magically appear in the frame below.</p>
```

Comment: I doubt that this is what the OP is looking for

Comment: ok, a comment was enough in that case, downvote was unnecessary.

Comment: it's nothing personal, I just didn't think this answer was helpful to the question. In any case, I added a space to your question so I could remove it in case someone lands on this page and decides to go with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Works for me... ;)

```
<div id="a" style="width:100%; text-align:right; border: 1px solid blue">
    <div id="b" style="width:600px; border:1px solid red">
        hi
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In IE 5 maybe :P ... a "DIV" is a "Block" element (by default), so "text-align" ***shouldn't*** move it to the right. So, all you've done is found a way to move it to the right in some crappy old browsers :)

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the width you want and make the margin-right: 0 and margin-left: auto

```
<div id="a">
<div id="b" style="width:600px; margin-right: 0; margin-left: auto;">
    If ID:A has a width of say 1000 then ID:B will have a left margin of 400px
</div>
</div>
```

or if ID:A is already inside a div anyway, you just need this:

```
<div id="a" style="width:600px; margin-right: 0; margin-left: auto;">
        If ID:A's wrapper has a width of say 1000 then ID:A 
        will have a left margin of 400px
</div>
```

The *total* width of a block element inside a block element is always the width of the container anyway.